# Sum/Count of dimension attributes in MDX

Tags: sql, ssas, mdx

I have a situation where I have to count all the accounts for which Account Category is municipal. Below is the snapshot that shows the dimension/attributes. Please look into it and advise. I have also tried using count/sum function but it did not help. Please guide me.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qX8Y2.jpg

Comment: I need MDX query please.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that the attribute you want to count is `[Account].[Account]`. Then you could define the count as a new measure using the [`Count` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144823.aspx) and use `[Account].[Account Category].[Municipal]` in the `WHERE` clause:

```
WITH Member Measures.[Municipal Count] AS
     [Account].[Account].[Account].Members.Count
SELECT { Measures.[Municipal Count] }
       ON COLUMNS
  FROM [Your Cube]
 WHERE [Account].[Account Category].[Municipal]
```